# Eloquent create says movie_id doesnt exist even though it does

Tags: laravel, eloquent

So basically I am trying to create a new row in the database with Eloquent create method but it doesnt work properly.

This is the code in my controller.

```php
$movie->review(request()->all() + ['user_id' => auth()->id()]);
```

And here is my Movie model

```php
class Movie extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'title', 'poster_path'
    ];

    public function reviews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
    }

    public function review($review)
    {
        $this->reviews()->create($review);
    }
}
```

And yes I have put movie_id in fillable in Review model.

```php
protected $fillable = [
    'movie_id', 'user_id', 'heading', 'rating', 'comment'
];
```

I checked if my form properly sends all data and it does.

```
  "_token" => "..."
  "movie_id" => "5"
  "rating" => "7"
  "heading" => "Test heading"
  "comment" => "Test comment"
  "user_id" => 1
```

And when I check the database everything is set beside movie_id. Its Null and I have no idea why.

Comment: Couple things; you should't have to pass a `movie_id` field if you're doing `$this->reviews->create(...)`, as `$this` should be aware of the current `Movie` and it's `id`. Second, you can use `request->input()` to avoid passing `_token` to your `review()` method. Lastly, it might be beneficial to have a `not null` setting on `reviews.movie_id`, as they're dependant. Beyond that, I'm not sure why this isn't working; at a glance everything looks ok.

Comment: @TimLewis I have debugged this for hours and honestly I have never been so frustrated. I use `$this->id` now and it still gives the same error. `Column 'movie_id' cannot be null` it complains that its null now since its no longer nullable. This project needs to be finished in 2 days and I'm so stressed.

Comment: @TimLewis I even tried using fake data `$test = ['movie_id' => $this->id, 'user_id' => 1, 'heading' => 'test', 'rating' => 5, 'comment' => 'commentkdkdkd']` but still complains that `movie_id` is null.

Comment: Craziness... I've never encountered such a persistent issue with saving a new record. Are you open to using `new Review(); $review->whatever = whatever; $review->save();` logic? I know that `create()` can be finicky sometimes, and I personally rarely use it.

Comment: @TimLewis I use `Review::create($request->all() + ['user_id' => auth()->id()])` now and it works! Thanks Tim. This is my first laravel project and it hasnt been a fun experience.

Comment: Nice; I was gonna suggest that direct `Review::create()` model function next, but glad you found it. And honestly, I love working with Laravel; I'd recommend sticking with it if you can. Once you figure out the nuances, it's a joy to use. Cheers!